# rake test doesn't recognize a new folder inside the test folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, tdd, rake

When I run `rake test`, it doesn't run tests in a new folder that I have created.

By default Rails has this folder inside the test folder:
 [image]

When I run test, i.e `rake test`, it tests the content of the test folder.

I have added an api folder inside the test folder.
[image]

The contents of the api folder are tested when I do this: `rake test:run TEST=test/api/users_test.rb`

But, when I just do `rake test`, it doesn't test the content of the api folder. How to configure it?

Comment: I am testing REST API. But I using Grape API for it. So, I create separate folder inside app that-why I assumption was that it should be in separate folder in test folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rake test:all` should run all tests in subdirectories of the test folder, even non-default ones.

If you want to make a `rake test:api` task: Do `rake -w test | grep '^rake test'` to see the files (in the railties gem) where Rails defines test tasks. In testing.rake you'll see how Rails defines tasks for the default subdirectories. Make a lib/tasks/test.rake and do the same thing for your new subdirectory:

```
Rails::TestTask.new('api' => "test:prepare") do |t|
  t.pattern = "test/api/**/*_test.rb"
end
```

Comment: Scweiguth Thanks Man, It help me lot.